# How to get number of repetition of each group of regexp in a line?

Tags: python, regex

How I can get number of repetitions of each group in regexp, using python, and get a list of this groups?

For example:
This regex `(ab)*.*?(cd)*` on the string `ababababcdcddscdcdfscdcd`
Should return `4` for the first group, because `ab` exists 4 times in the string.
And return `6` for the second group, because `cd` exists 6 times in the string.

This or maybe another function should also return a list of groups and another part of the line. For this string it must be list with `[ab,ab,ab,ab,cd,cd,ds,cd,cd,fs,cd,cd]`. I tried to use match object, but I can't find a way to get the number of repetitions of every group.

Thanks very much everybody for the help.

Answer (score 0):

When you quantify a capture group, it just captures the first match, not all the matches, so you can't get `[ab, ab, ab, ab, ...]`.

You an put the quantifier inside a group, so that all the repetitions will be captured at once.

```
((ab)*).*?((cd)*)
```

The capture groups will be:

```
["abababab", "ab", "cdcdcdcdcdcd", "cd"]
```

You can divide the length of the even elements by the length of the following element to get the number of repetitions.

Answer (score 0):

In your pattern you are repeating a capturing group which will give you the value of the last iteration in a group. So for example this part `(ab)*` will contain the value of the last occurrence of ab.

```
matched ()()()
        abababab
              () captured
```

One option is to split on either ab or cd using a capturing group `(ab|cd)` to keep the delimiter and remove the empty entries from the result.

For example

```
import re
s = "ababababcdcddscdcdfscdcd"
pattern = r"(ab|cd)"
result = list(filter(None, re.split(pattern, s)))
print(result)
```

Output

```
['ab', 'ab', 'ab', 'ab', 'cd', 'cd', 'ds', 'cd', 'cd', 'fs', 'cd', 'cd']
```

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/GT60f7)